# How to filter records based on date in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

How to filter the record in the table based on the date column. I am using the following code for the filter, but its throwing error like

> ***ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null***

```
temp = [{ "firstName":"Ravi", "date":"2019-04-04T06:12:43.541Z", "status":"created" }, { "firstName":"Shagul", "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z", "status":"created" }, { "firstName":"Abdul", "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z", "status":"created" }, { "firstName":"Gani", "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z", "status":"created" }];

public updateFilter(event) {
const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
    return (
    d.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 ||
    d.date.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== 1 ||
    d.status.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 ||
    !val
  );
});

 this.rows = temp;
 this.table.offset = 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show what is `this.temp`?

Comment: [ {  
      "firstName":"Ravi",
      "date":"2019-04-04T06:12:43.541Z",
      "status":"created"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Shagul",
      "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z",
      "status":"created"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Abdul",
      "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z",
      "status":"created"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Gani",
      "date":"2019-04-05T06:12:43.541Z",
      "status":"created"
   }
]

Comment: And may I know what is `val`?

Comment: @Vedha Thanks Please add the filter value so anyone can help

Comment: const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

Comment: The best way is to show the HTML Code! Will help

Comment: @Vedha Do you want the exact match from list? Like I searched `Ravi` then first object or if i `Rav` then also it should display the first object/

Comment: Your debugger should show you where exactly the error occurs. Check this before asking questions like "there is an error somewhere in my code". The lines of code you showed us should not throw that error, as toLowerCase() won't return null.

Comment: @Vedha I have updated my code. let me know if it works?

Comment: @Vedha added an answer with date picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can infer from your code, `temp` is the 'temporary' store which stores the filtered, data, right? And I assume `val` is the filter string.

You are close, but you will need to make the following amendments:

```
updateFilter(event) {
  const temp = this.temp.filter(d => {
    const firstNameMatch = d.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val; 
    const dateMatch =  d.date.indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val; 
    const statusMatch = d.status.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val; 

    return firstNameMatch || dateMatch || statusMatch;
  });
  this.rows = temp;
  this.table.offset = 0;
}
```

As for date, I did not use `toLowerCase()` as I am not sure your search string is capitalised or not. (eg. 2019-04-04T06:12:43.541Z)

Comment: Sure :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
updateFilter(event) {
  var val = event.value.toLowerCase();

  const temp = this.temp.filter(x => x.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1
    || x.status.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1
    || x.date.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1);
  console.log(temp);
}
```

As per assumption, you need to filter records by Date only so I have updated [`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uu5cae) with DatePicker Demo.

Comment: @Vedha Glad, it helped!